# Jquery once toggle issues in Firefox with Drupal10

Tags: jquery, drupal

I'm having trouble figuring out the nuances of the once library when using Jquery with Drupal 10. I've got this far, which works fine in Chromem Edge, and in my dev environment in Firefox, but it simply doesn't work in Firefox production. There are no error logs, the console is clean aside. The links are just dead.

The aim here is to reuse the same code for all toggle instances, using a data-id variable to make each link and relevant content unique so I don't have to clutter my code with a function for every link.

My current code is as follows:

```
`(function($, Drupal, once) {
  Drupal.behaviors.toggleLink = {
    attach: function(context) {
      $(once('toggleLink', '.togglelink', context)).each(function() {
        $(this).on('click', function(event) {
        var btnId5 = $(this).data('id');
        $('.hidecontent' + btnId5, context).toggle(400);
        });
      });
    }
  };
}(jQuery, Drupal, once));`
```

edit to add: I'm currently using jQuery 3.7.0

Comment: Probably, clearing the cache, and restarting the server or pod could help.

Comment: @XabIon. I've tried both. And the problem persists in incognito mode, too. I added console.log() and suddenly it validated and the links worked once or twice in FF. Then the links and the console log went dead. Other jQuery on the page still works, so this seems to be something to do with the Once call?

Comment: If that is the case, I will suggest finding another way without once.

Comment: is your jquery code present on the page, add console.log to check if the code is present.